# Twig: variable override set in previous template

Tags: templates, twig

I have 2 templates and I want to override the variable `body_class` from main template. This is the code I have so far.

Main Template:

```
{# main.html.twig #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    {% block head %}
        {% block head_meta %}
            // ...
        {% endblock %}
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            // ...
        {% endblock %}
        {% block icon %}
            <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
        {% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
    </head>
    {% set body_class = '' %}
    <body class="main {{ body_class }}">
        {% block navi %}{% endblock %}
        {% block error %}{% endblock %}
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}
            // ...
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Second template:

```
{# dashboard.html.twig #}

{% set body_class = 'dashboard' %}
{% extends 'main.html.twig' %}

{% block head %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
{% block head_meta %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Dashboard!{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    I'm dashboard!
{% endblock %}
```

I tried placing `{% set body_class = 'dashboard' %}` before extend statement and after, but that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not set `body_class` in your `main.html.twig` file. `dashboard.html.twig` is all good, just change `main.html.twig`:

Remove `{% set body_class = '' %}` line and change `<body class="main {{ body_class }}">` to `<body class="main {{ body_class|default('') }}">`.

That way you have your `body_class` variable value `''` as a [default](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/default.html) value when it's not defined and `'dashboard'` when you set it from your `dashboard.html.twig` file.

If you set a variable in your base file, in this case `main.html.twig`, then you can't overwrite it from inheriting templates.

Answer (score 0):

Variables from child themes **are accessible** by their parents but get overriden as soon as you redeclare them in the parent.

So you can simply declare the variable in the parent only if is not defined:

```
{# main.html.twig #}

...
{% set body_class = body_class is defined ? body_class : '' %}
<body class="main {{ body_class }}">
...
```

```
{# dashboard.html.twig #}

{% extends 'main.html.twig' %}
{% set body_class = 'dashboard' %}
```